# What is the default character set in SQLAlchemy for MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to move a database from `utf8mb3` to `utf8mb4`. In my code I create an engine:

```py
url = make_url(database_url)
if 'charset' not in url.query:
    url = url.update_query_pairs([("charset", "utf8")])
create_engine(str(url))
```

I have database with character set `utf8mb4` and I have these entries in `my.cnf`:

```ini
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

So the question is: When I create my SQLAlchemy engine, what will the character set be? Will it be `utf8mb4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what will the character set be? Will it be `utf8mb4`?

No, because you specify the equivalent of `charset=utf8` in the connection URL and MySQL interprets that as `utf8mb3`

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

base_url = sa.URL.create(
    "mysql+mysqldb",
    username="scott",
    password="tiger",
    host="localhost",
    port=3307,
    database="test",
)

url = base_url.update_query_pairs([("charset", "utf8")])
engine = sa.create_engine(url)
cnxn = engine.raw_connection().driver_connection
print(cnxn.character_set_name())  # utf8mb3
```

Instead, use `utf8mb4` specifically:

```py
url = base_url.update_query_pairs([("charset", "utf8mb4")])
engine = sa.create_engine(url)
cnxn = engine.raw_connection().driver_connection
print(cnxn.character_set_name())  # utf8mb4
```